# The inequality $\limsup \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} \geqslant \limsup \sqrt[n]{c_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, limsup-and-liminf

$c_n>0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, prove$$\limsup \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} \geqslant \limsup \sqrt[n]{c_n}$$
Tried to present $\sqrt[n]{c_n}=c_1 \frac{c_2}{c_1}...\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$. Seemingly $\sqrt[n]{c_n}$ is some kind of mean of $c_1$ to  $c_{n+1}/c_{n}$. However nothing can be done...any hint?

Answer (score 3):

Let $l := \limsup_{n \to \infty}c_{n+1}/c_{n}$; let $\varepsilon > 0$; then there is some $N \geq 1$ such that
$n \geq N$ only if
$c_{n+1}/c_{n} < l+\varepsilon$,
only if
$c_{N+p} < c_{N}(l+\varepsilon)^{p}$
for all $p \geq 1$ by induction,
only if
$c_{n} < c_{N}(l + \varepsilon)^{n-N}$
for all $n \geq N$,
only if $c_{n}^{1/n} < c_{N}^{1/n}(l + \varepsilon)^{1 - \frac{N}{n}}$ for all $n \geq N$,
and only if
$\limsup_{n \to \infty}c_{n}^{1/n} \leq l + \varepsilon$;
this argument holds for every $\varepsilon > 0$,
so we have
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty}c_{n}^{1/n} \leq l.
$$